# Cloudwatch custom metrics namespace in Grafana

Tags: spring, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

My application is pushing custom metrics to CloudWatch. Furthermore, these metrics are plotted using Grafana.

For this to work I need to configure Grafana to look for my custom metrics namespaces by adding them under Datasources -> CloudWatch. Like this:
[image]

The only problem is that I'm having another custom metric namespace called "MyApp (prod,en)". Since there is a comma in the namespace itself, it messes up the list above (which is comma separated).

I have not chosen the namespace name myself. Is was automatically generated. It's a Spring boot app called MyApp using 2 spring profiles: 'prod' and 'en'

My questions is how do I get the metrics from the namespace "MyApp (prod,en)" into Grafana?

Comment: What is a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the namespace name to "MyApp (prod en)" when initializing the CloudWatchConfig. This fixed my problem.